# Docker Compose and multiple subnets

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm struggling with `Docker` `Compose` (version 2 or 3).
I'm trying to add multiple `subnets`, so various services can reach each other, but get assigned `IPv4` addresses from different subnets.

This is my current configuration:

```
networks:
  custom:
    driver: "bridge"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.10.0/16
          gateway: 10.10.10.1
        - subnet: 100.100.100.0/16
          gateway: 100.100.100.1
```

But I get the error:

```
Creating network "docker-setup-test_custom" with driver "bridge"
ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

Comment: You can't have a subnet that overlaps another subnet.

Comment: But they don't overlap?

Comment: It can't overlap _any_ other Docker network, including ones previously created.

Comment: Ah, found some old networks in `docker network list`. Thank you.

Comment: Now I'm getting a new error: `ERROR: bridge driver doesn't support multiple subnets`.

Comment: @AlfredBalle I'm running into the same issue with the bridge driver. Did you find a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the network config as specified in the documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

Otherwhise I believe all containers in the same docker compose can communicate without network config.